# Debug information for javax.net is not written to Domino server console

Tags: java, debugging, xpages, lotus-domino

In my XPages application, I want to debug a problem related to **javax.net**. Therefore I set the system property `javax.net.debug=all`. Unfortunately, the debug information is not written to the Domino server console and I cannot find it in any of the logs on the server.

Can anybody tell me how to get that debug output?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but I have found the LogReader from OpenNTF https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=opendocument&name=xpages%20log%20file%20reader to be very useful on a daily basis when working with XPages.

Comment: @RobMason: Thanks for the tip. I already use this helpful tool but I can't find the debug information in any of the logs provided by it.

Comment: How did you set the property?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: I set it in the code via `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) In your Notes.ini, create an entry for an options file, i.e.

```
JavaOptionsFile=C:\IBM\Domino9\MyJavaOptions.txt
```

2) Create this file and add this line

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

3) Save it & restart the server

4) Open log.nsf to see what happens - the server console is no longer useable, too much debug information!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 2 questions: [1] Why does the JVM not accept setting the property via System.setProperty? [2] By "the server console is no longer useable" you probably mean that there is just a lot of output. Or does the server crash or stop working? I'm asking because I do not plan to have the debugging activated for long, just for a few minutes to get the output...

Comment: There is a lot of output.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think the option must be set before javax.net is initated. And that's why you have to add the option before the JVM starts, otherwise it is too late.

Comment: I was just wondering about that because in the non-Domino JVM I also use `System.setProperty("java.net.debug","all")` during runtime and there it works as expected. Anyway: I'll try what you suggested and will report back here.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer - it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add to entry `javax.net.debug=all` to file `\Domino\data\domino\workspace\.config\rcpinstall.properties`
2. Restart server

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already got the problem fixed thanks to @SvenHasselbach. Just in case you are new and/or missed it: The green checkmark next to an answer (in this case Sven's) means that it is accepted.

Comment: I know what green mark means.  This is alternative answer.