# Xpages : Java custom rest service throws javax.net.ssl.SSL.HandShakeException

Tags: java, rest, ssl, xpages

I am using Xpages Rest Custom Service to call a **url which is SSL enabled**.
The xpage and the url sits on the the same database on same server.

The Java code below

String xsdPath = "https://domx.xxx.com:460/james/dev/xmlxsd.nsf/students.xsd";

URL schemaFile = new URL(xsdPath);

Please find the screenshot of the error below.

What are the steps to get access to the SSL sites using Java code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: From which CA was the SSL Certificate signed?

Comment: It would be helpful to have more details about the exception. You could set the system property `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` of the JVM as described by @SvenHasselbach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40806388/1697566 . But be warned that this produces a lot of output in the server console/log, so I recommend to activate it, run the code that produces the exception and deactivate the debug option right afterwards.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Can share the solution please?